# Excel Conditional Formatting doesn't work comparing dates (2 rules)

Tags: excel, date, formatting, conditional-statements, rules

I'm trying to apply Conditional Formatting to do two things:

- Identify if a date in column #1 (D) is later than column #2 (E)
- Identify if the date in column #2 (E) is more than three years old

I've set up two rules:

```
 Formula: =D3>E3                (highlights the cell in yellow if true)
 Cell Value >='today()-1095'    (turns font color red if true)
```

It will highlight the cell if #2 is older than #1, but nothing I do will get the font to turn red if it is more than three years old. I've tried multiple variations on the rules and tried moving each one up and down above/below the other - nothing is working.

Help!

Comment: If you want it to turn red if the date is more than three years old, you need to use, use `Cell Value <= today()-1095`

Comment: That's valid (I had it looking the wrong way), but I still either don't get the highlighted cell if it's an earlier date than the column to the left, or if I have the highlight I don't have the red font. *THIS* is where I'm having problems.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following formula:

```
=YEARFRAC(A1,TODAY())>=3
```

[image]

Comment: Same problem - either red text or yellow highlighting, but not both.

Comment: Ah, I did not understand you wanted both conditions to apply _at the same time_. AFAIK You can't apply two conditions simultaneously. Instead create a third condition were formulas are true. So use `=D3>E3`, `=YEARFRAC(A1,TODAY())>=3` and `AND(D3>E3, YEARFRAC(A1,TODAY())>=3)`

Comment: I was able to get it to work before, but that was about a year ago, so ... tried your solution, and it worked. Thanks!